# Prevent content overlap with fixed positioning after pinch to zoom

Tags: javascript, ios, css, position, fixed

I have a `position:fixed` sidebar on my site on the left with other content to the right. On a desktop browser, when you zoom in, all page content scales appropriately as you would expect. But if you pinch to zoom in on iOS, the content on the right slides underneath the fixed sidebar. The sidebar zooms in size but is always fixed to the edge of the screen. Now I noticed with Safari on Mac when you pinch to zoom in, that's not the case - it appears to revert to static positioning because the sidebar may not be fully visible - it doesn't get fixed to the screen. That's the desired behavior I want on iOS. Is there some way I can do that, besides trying to detect scale changes and manually changing the style to absolute/fixed? Thanks!

Comment: I understand you dont want to use media queries but that is your best solution and it will increase the UX of your website

Comment: I am open to media queries. But I don't want to simply revert them to static positioning for mobile devices. The sidebar should be truly fixed when scrolling the right-hand content. Only when they zoom in I don't want the sidebar to still be fixed to the screen.

Comment: If you are still interested in an answer, it would be good to supply a code example. The answer could be as simple as a missing CSS declaration like "position:absolute" on one element.